# How should I write this sql query so I only grab numbers that don't exist in user table?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two tables structured like so

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :facebook_id
      t.string :phone_number

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :numbers do |t|
      t.string :number, :unique => true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I need to write a query that grabs numbers from the numbers table
I need the query to only grab numbers if there is no users with that particular number or if there is a user with that number if there Facebook_id is blank then go ahead and grab that number

here's what I have so far but it only seems to grab numbers if there is a user with that number

```
numbers = Number.joins('left join users on numbers.number = users.phone_number').where('users.facebook_id LIKE ? and numbers.number is not null','')
```

Comment: Is the point of this query to check if the phone number is unique identifier in your user model?

Comment: I think the crux of your issue is you are trying to query against 2 tables that have no association.  I would recommend re-examining your paradigm and reworking the models and migrations to fit the use case.  

What is the relationship between User and Number?  One-to-One, One-to-Many, Many-to-Many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to place your search conditions in your `LEFT JOIN ... ON` clause. Mentioning in your `WHERE` clause a column belonging to the right-side table in a `LEFT JOIN` converts it to `INNER JOIN`.

Try this:

```
'left join users on numbers.number = users.phone_number AND users.phone_number IS NULL'
```

gets your missing-phone-number criterion.

I'm not sure I understand your blank facebook id criterion. But you might try this

```
'left join users on numbers.number = users.phone_number 
                  AND (    users.phone_number IS NULL
                        OR users.facebook_id IS NULL
                        OR LENGTH(users.facebook_id) = 0'
```